# Passing by reference or value of reference types as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, class, parameters, reference

I learned in C# reference types are passed by values through parameters unless with `out` or `ref` keywords. Recently I wrote some test code to verify this and some specifications and got some **unexpected result**.

The basic ideas are: I shared some variables `Cls`(of class `TestClass`) and `Str` (a string) between members of Foo and Bar. Some members of Bar are assigned directly, some by parameters, and some by parameters with `ref` keyword. Then I change these variables in `Foo`.

I am expecting those members of `Bar` assigned by value won't change, and those by reference will. But except the string properties they all changes.

Here are the codes

```
public class FieldsAndProperties
    {
        private Foo foo;
        private Bar bar;
        public void Test()

        {
            string Str = "Original String";
            TestClass Cls = new TestClass { Content = "Original Content" };

            // These parts are seemingly passed by reference
            this.foo = new Foo
            {
                FooStringField = Str,
                FooStringProp = Str,
                FooTestField = Cls,
                FooTestProp = Cls
            };

            // -------------------------NOTICE-------------------------------------
            // I was expecting the first parameter to be passed by value, thus 
            // what it assigns to won't change after I change Cls.
            this.bar = new Bar(Cls, ref Cls);

            // I was expecting them passed by value, yet the test tells otherwise.
            this.bar.ChangeThroughPara(Cls, Cls);
            // ----------------------END OF NOTICE---------------------------------

            // bar members that are related to Str and Cls by direct assigning (by reference).
            this.bar.BarStringField = Str;
            this.bar.BarStringProp = Str;
            this.bar.BarTestField = Cls;
            this.bar.BarTestProp = Cls;

            ///<remarks>
            /// Here is where I change the <see cref="Cls"/>, which is also 
            /// tied with <see cref="foo.FooTestField"/> and <see cref="foo.FooTestProp"/>
            ///</remarks>
            this.foo.Change();

            Console.WriteLine(this.bar.ToString());

            return;
        }
    }

    class TestClass
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public string FooStringField;

        public string FooStringProp { get; set; }

        public TestClass FooTestField;

        public TestClass FooTestProp { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// I suppose here <see cref="FooStringField"/>, <see cref="FooStringProp"/>
        /// <see cref="FooTestField"/>, <see cref="FooTestProp"/> be assigned, also 
        /// changing the instance referenced by <see cref="Cls"/> and <see cref="Str"/>.
        /// And this is verified by the test.
        /// </summary>
        public void Change()
        {
            this.FooStringField = "Foo String";
            this.FooStringProp = "Foo String";

            this.FooTestField.Content = "Foo Content";
            this.FooTestProp.Content = "Foo Content";
        }
    }

    class Bar
    {
        public string BarStringField;
        public string BarStringProp { get; set; }
        public TestClass BarTestField;
        public TestClass BarTestProp { get; set; }
        public TestClass BarConsField;        
        public TestClass BarConsProp { get; set; }
        public TestClass BarRefField;
        public TestClass BarRefProp { get; set; }
        public TestClass BarParaField;
        public TestClass BarParaProp { get; set; }


        // -----------------------------------NOTICE---------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor test.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="barCons">
        /// I assumed it to be passed by value, thus when <see cref="Cls"/> changes,
        /// <see cref="BarConsField"/> and <see cref="BarConsProp"/> remains the same,
        /// however it is not the case during testing.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="barRef">
        /// Passed by reference, expected change after <see cref="Change()"/>, and it
        /// does
        /// </param>
        public Bar(TestClass barCons, ref TestClass barRef)
        {
            this.BarConsField = barCons;
            this.BarConsProp = barCons;
            this.BarRefField = barRef;
            this.BarRefProp = barRef;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Expecting no change in <see cref="BarParaField"/> and <see cref="BarParaProp"/>
        /// after <see cref="Change()"/>, however test tells otherwise.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="field"></param>
        /// <param name="prop"></param>
        public void ChangeThroughPara(TestClass field, TestClass prop)
        {
            this.BarParaField = field;
            this.BarParaProp = prop;
        }

        //----------------------------------END OF NOTICE-------------------------------------
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Field: {this.BarStringField}   Property: {this.BarStringProp} \n" +
                $"FieldTest: {this.BarTestField.Content}   PropTest: {this.BarTestProp.Content} \n" +
                $"FieldCons: {this.BarConsField.Content}   PropCons: {this.BarConsProp.Content} \n" +
                $"FieldRef: {this.BarRefField.Content}   PropRef:   {this.BarRefProp.Content} \n" +
                $"FieldPara: {this.BarParaField.Content}   PropPara:   {this.BarParaProp.Content} \n";
        }
    }
```

The results are:
[image: Every member except strings in Bar changed!]

**So here are the questions:**

1. Why are those passed as parameters **still appears to refer to** the `Cls` and **affected** afterward. Aren't they supposed to be passed by value?
2. I thought strings are also reference types, why aren't they affected?

Comment: You'll need to go back and review the pertinent documentation again. See marked duplicates for additional information, especially Jon Skeet's excellent articles regarding reference vs. value types, and parameter passing. You have a lot going on in your code example, but the short version is: when passing by value, _members_ of reference types can be modified by the called method, but the caller's _reference_ to the object cannot. The `string` type is a reference type, but it's immutable; methods that "modify" a string, actually return a whole new instance. The original is left unchanged.

Comment: Also keep in mind that when you use `ref` or `out`, the thing that is "by reference" is only the variable being passed, and the reference is only valid for the duration of the method call. The variable still holds a _value_ and assigning that value to some other variable loses the "by reference" nature of the variable. Only the _variable_ is "by reference". The value itself remains a simple value (a reference for reference types and an actual value for value types).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Excuse me. I don't think that is what I am asking. Where I am confusing is where I assign `Cls` to members of `bar` _by value_. Since it is by value, I suppose what assigned to members of `bar` should be a new instance of the type, no longer relevant to the original one. But how can it be changed when I changed the `Cls`(the original one). Your explanation about strings is good though, thanks. **Also** Would you provide a link to the question which you think I duplicating with?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Now I get it. Thank you very much. Still, if I want to copy only the values(members), what should I do?

Comment: _"Would you provide a link"_ -- links to the duplicate questions can be found in the banner now present above your question. _" if I want to copy only the values(members), what should I do?"_ -- not sure what you're asking. "By reference" vs "by value" applies only to parameter passing. Assignment from one variable to another is always "copying values". If you only want to copy the values of class members, then just assign the values of class members from one variable to another.